# How to create layout for smartphone and tablet with Appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an application with Appcelerator Studio to Android. I have used only Android Tablet but now, I should to use also a smartphone. If I try to open the application, the layout is not correct, the layout is too big for the smartphone's screen.

Now, there is a way to adapt the layout for tablet and smartphone?

For example, this is my Login box:

login.xml
    
        
            
            Accedi

```
        <TextField id="username" class="textLogin" hintText="Insert username"></TextField>
        <TextField id="password" class="textLogin" hintText="Insert password" 
            passwordMask="true"></TextField>


        <View  id="buttons_container" >

            <!--<Button id="changeLanguageButton" class="buttonLanguage"
                onClick="languageListener" >Lingua</Button>-->

            <Button id="loginButton" class="buttonLogin">Login</Button>

            <Button id="emergencyButton" class="buttonEmergency">Emergency</Button>

        </View> <!-- end buttons_container -->

    </View>
</Alloy>
```

login.tss

```
".container" : {
    backgroundColor: "#666",
    width : 600,
    height : 500,
    layout : "vertical",
    borderRadius : 40,
    borderWidth : 2,
    // borderColor : "#E6E6E6",
    borderColor: "#fff",
}

".images":{
    top: 20,
    // left: "161px",
    backgroundImage : "/images/logo_decipher.png",
    width : "402px",
    height: "62px",
    // height : "80px"
}

".loginLable":{
    top : 20,
    color : "#B3B3B3",
    textAlign : "center",
    width: '340px',
    font : {
        fontSize : "20pt",
        fontWeight : "Italic"
    }
}

".textLogin":{
    top : 20,
    height : "60px",
    backgroundColor : "#c9c9c9",
    borderRadius : 10,
    borderWidth : 1,
    borderColor : "#fff",
    color : "#fff",
    width: '340px',
    font : {
            fontFamily : 'Roboto-Regular',
            fontSize : "14pt",
            fontWeight : "Regular"
    }, 
    paddingLeft : 10
}


"#buttons_container": {
    top: 80,
    width: 340,
    height: 60,
}


".buttonLogin":{
    left: 0,
    width: 160,
    height : 60,
    backgroundColor : "#29ABE2",
    borderRadius : 10,
    borderColor: "#fff" 
}

".buttonEmergency":{
    right: 0,
    width: 160,
    height : 60,
    backgroundColor : "#29ABE2",
    borderRadius : 10,
    borderColor: "#fff"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this out. Providers guidelines you can use. http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/02/understanding-titanium-views/

Answer (score 0):

You can use device size specific conditions in your styles in login.tss. For example:

```
".container[formFactor=tablet]" : {
   width : 800,
   height : 600
},
".container[formFactor=handheld]" : {
   width : 600,
   height : 400
}
```

or special condition attributes in your login.xml

```
<View id="main" width="600" layout="vertical" formFactor="handheld">
...
</View>
<View id="main" width="1024" layout="horizontal" formFactor="tablet">
...
</View>
```

You can find more details here:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_XML_Markup-section-46248608_AlloyXMLMarkup-ConditionalCode